# JQuery: variable from .change not showing up in .load

Tags: php, jquery

I'm setting up dynamic pulldowns: the choice on select#category informs the contents of select#subcat.

this is the html for select#category:

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option>Click Here to choose a category</option>
           <?php foreach ($categories as $key => $category) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $category ?></option>
           <?php } ?>         
</select>

<select name="subcat" id="subcat">
    <option>&lt;-- First Choose a Category</option>                           
</select>
```

this is the jQuery statement:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#category").change(function(){
        $("select#subcat").load("subcats.php",{ id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'});
    });
});
```

this is subcats.php:

```
<?php
      //source of categories
      include("config.php") ;
      //initiate option list
      $options =  '<option value="">Choose a Sub-category</option>'."\n" ;
      if(!empty($_GET["id"])) {
      //iterate through the categories
      foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
      if ($_GET["id"] == $key) {
      //select the data source
      $subcats = file('subcat/'.$key.'.dat', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) ;
      natsort($subcats);
      //create the rest of the option list
          foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
          list ($subname,$subkey ) =explode ("\t", $subcat) ;
           $options .=  '<option value="'.$subkey.'">'.$subname.'</option>'."\n" ;
      }
      echo  $options ;   
          }
      }
      }  else {
      // if no variable given provide option list as error check
      echo  '<option value="">&lt;-- Choose a Category First</option>
      <option value="">Foo Bar</option>'."\n" ;   
          }
      ?>
```

My understanding is that `id: $(this).val()` provides the selected option from `select#category` for use in the php document; am I off base here? Really, if I'm reading the docs right, I shouldn't even need the `, { id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}` bit
the ajax request `.load` is working, because the error check menu items appear in the `select#subcats`.

However, that's all that appears: the variable does not seem to be getting through...

Li'l help here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: does `$(this).val()` not refer to `$("select#subcat")`?

Comment: Here `this` is in the context of the `select#category` change handler, so it should still be `select#category`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `console.log($(this).val())` before .load to debug the submitted value

are you sure the data is send per get method?

> Example: Same as above, but will POST
>   the additional parameters to the
>   server and a callback that is executed
>   when the server is finished
>   responding.
>
> `$("#feeds").load("feeds.php", {limit:
>   25}, function(){ alert("The last 25
>   entries in the feed have been
>   loaded"); });`

and as found under the comments on http://api.jquery.com/load/

> According to the documentation: "The
>   POST method is used if data is
>   provided as an object; otherwise, GET
>   is assumed."

You could simply use `$_REQUEST['id']` instead of `$_GET['id']` or `$_POST['id']` to cover both (see [php.net::$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) for more informations)

Comment: Yes!!!! Thank You!! When I changed it to $_POST (or $_REQUEST) it worked; and I can leave the id as : "id: $(this).val()" (It was the only thing I hadn't tried, I think)

Answer (score 0):

In your situation `this` belongs to `select#subcat`. Try to use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("select#category").change(function(){
      $("select#subcat").load("subcats.php",{ id: $("select#category").val(), ajax: 'true'});
   })
})
```

Comment: Alexander - In the code, `this` would actually still refer to the `select#category`. It would only refer to `select#subcat` if it was in a callback to the `.load()` method. As it is, it's just part of the object that is passed as the second parameter to `.load()`. So `$(this).val()` will be evaluated before `.load()` ever runs. :o)